# Blazor not detecting service in blazor component base?

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to dependency inject my http class into my component base file which each component inherits from.

But when I compile am getting the following error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
> Error (active)    CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to
> the required parameter 'ihttpInterface' of
> 'QuizCardBase.QuizCardBase(IhttpInterface)'   BlazorQuiz  G:\GitMaster\BlazorQuiz\BlazorQuiz\BlazorQuiz\Components\Pages\Quiz\Questions.razor 2

I have the http service hooked up in my services as such.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IhttpInterface, BlazorQuizApiService>();
```

So my Question is why am I getting the above error.

```
public class QuizCardBase : ComponentBase
{
    protected readonly IhttpInterface _httpInterface;
      
    public  QuizCardBase (IhttpInterface ihttpInterface)
    {
        _httpInterface = ihttpInterface;
    }

    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; } = new List<Question>();
    protected int questionIndex = 0;
    protected int score = 0;

    protected void OptionSelected(string option)
    {
        if (option == Questions[questionIndex].Answer)
        {
            score++;
        }
        questionIndex++;
    }
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        LoadQuestions();

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
    public void TrackAnswers()
    {
        
    }

    private void LoadQuestions()
    {
          // here i want to use my interface to load questions
    }
```

Here is my html for completness

```
@page "/quiz"
@using BlazorQuiz.Pages
@inherits QuizCardBase

<div class="container">
    <div class="quiz">

        @if (questionIndex < Questions.Count())
        {
            <div class="app-title">
                Quizzing!
            </div>
            <div class="quiz-header">
                @Questions[questionIndex].QuestionText
            </div>
            <div class="quiz-body">
                @foreach (var option in Questions[questionIndex].Options)
                {
                    <OptionCard Option="@option" OnOptionSelected="OptionSelected"></OptionCard>
                }
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="app-title">
                @if (score > (Questions.Count / 2))
                {
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/100/000000/prize--v1.png" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/96/000000/lose.png" />
                }
            </div>
        }

        <button @onclick="SubmitQuiz">Submit Quiz</button>


    </div>
</div>
@code {
    private void SubmitQuiz()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: [Inject] public IhttpInterface ihttpInterface {get;set; } remove the constructor way...

Comment: How Do I new it up then must I pass it from the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.razor` files injection is done either via `@inject` in the markup area or less common `[Inject]` attribute placed on a property in the `@code` area or code behind.

In your case as you are creating a base component the markup will be ignored. Use the property attribute approach.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IhttpInterface, BlazorQuizApiService>();
```

is still required.

In your code block place:

```
[Inject]
protected IhttpInterface BlazorQuizApiService {get;set;}
```

As you inject by interface in this case, I gave the Property the same name as the implemented type,

Comment: But how does one set it or do it do that by the inject parameter?

Comment: Done this way your "LoadQuestions" method will have access to the injected service on and after `OnInitialized{Async}`